# DotNetZip in C# webapp - how to change the name of the zip folder structure

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

this is the code in my app

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + "filename.zip");
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AddEntry(@"F:\My Pictures\2011\DSC04854.jpg", @"\");
                zip.AddEntry(@"F:\My Pictures\2011\DSC04854.jpg", @"\");
                zip.AddEntry(@"F:\My Pictures\2011\DSC04854.jpg", @"\");
                zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
            }
            Response.Close();
```

I would like to create a zip file with a simplified folder structure (namely one folder) that gets written as output.

I have seen some answers to similar questions and I have tried many suggestions however I do not get the desired outcome. This code produces a zip file with the full folder structure.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using AddEntry, what you want is AddFile; the 2nd parameter to AddFile (when a string) is the internal directory.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the entries to the Zip, the second parameter could be left empty to place the files in the root of the folder.

```
zip.AddEntry(link_to_file.format, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but using `zip.AddFiles(filePaths)` still create full hierarchical zip file. I come cross another overload that simply solve this problem. just use:
`zip.AddFiles(filePaths,false,".")`
the second parameter is > preserve the hierarchical structure
the third parameter is the structure you just want to use to produce zip file. using

> "." means no nested folder allowed or simply zip on the current folder!